# MySQL 5.5 performance in Windows 7

Tags: database

My collegues and I are working on a Drupal 7 project. From time to time, we need to do a clean install on our machines (to get the latest updates working).
However, when installing the Drupal database, my collegues laptop is much faster than mine, despite the fact I've got the latest and most powerfull laptop (Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bit and 8GB of RAM).

What causes this lack of performance in installing the new Drupal website? I reinstalled MySQL 5 times, and still I don't see any improvement.

Answer (score 1):

This is funny. [*I just answered a question about MySQL 5.5 being slow in the DBA StackExchange*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6526/query-runs-a-long-time-in-some-newer-mysql-versions/6542#6542). You will have to configure it to perform better. It is not automatically configured for high performance by default.